# Apply convolution to a specific area of image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to apply convolution to a rectangle with specific from an image.
If I use [`filter2d`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType)) function it will apply convolution to entire image.

Also, I think a solution could be to  crop the original image, apply `filter2d` to cropped image and copy cropped image over original image, but I don't think is the best solution.
How can I achieve convolution just for a specific area of image?

Comment: does subimaging work? cv::Rect yourImageRegion = cv::Rect(...); filter2D(image(yourImageRegion), image(yourImageRegion), ...);

Comment: @Micka Yes, it works. But this is the most efficient way?

Comment: Memory usage should be O1, isn't it?

Comment: subimaging is ecfficient. But in-place editing syntax ofzen isn't, because temporary memory will be allocated. So if you are working on multiple images of the same size (e.g videostream) it might be better to allocate and use different source and destination images (.clone) and then filter on their subimages.

Comment: if only that subimage is relevant, you can use image(yourImageRegion).copyTo(...) where the target can be an empty Mat or a subimage of same size as the input (but different position if wanted).

Comment: you can use warping, but it is more expensive. There should be some tutorials or sample code online.